# Set default value in DatePicker Antd with React-Hook-Form V7

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-hook-form

I'm trying to **set the default value** for `Datepicker` when fetching data from a server, but it didn't work. Followed the docs [in here](https://ant.design/docs/react/faq-cn#%E5%BD%93%E6%88%91%E5%8A%A8%E6%80%81%E6%94%B9%E5%8F%98-defaultValue-%E7%9A%84%E6%97%B6%E5%80%99%E5%AE%83%E5%B9%B6%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%E7%94%9F%E6%95%88%E3%80%82), I cannot set the `defaultValue` props because it is only used for first rendering.

I figure out a solution is creating a state and update that state when `Datepicker` change. But it seems stupid because it re-render each updating. Please let me know a "better solution" or using the "state" of react-hook-form value. Here is my current "stupid solution":

```
import { DatePicker, Form } from "antd";
import moment, { Moment } from "moment";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Controller,
  ControllerRenderProps,
  SubmitHandler,
  useForm,
} from "react-hook-form";

const UserList = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<Moment | null>();
  const dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
  useEffect(() => {
    setDate(() => moment("1963-10-14T00:00:00"));
  }, []);

  const onChange = (date: Moment | null, dateString: string) => {
    console.log(date, dateString);
  };

  interface IForm {
    dob: string;
  }

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    control,
    reset,
    getValues,
    watch,
  } = useForm<IForm>({
    // resolver: yupResolver(UserInfoSchema),
  });

  const dateWatch = watch("dob");

  const handleSubmitForm: SubmitHandler<IForm> = (data: IForm) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const onDatePickerChange = (
    date: moment.Moment | null,
    dateString: string,
    props: any
  ) => {
    console.log(dateWatch);
    setDate(date);
    props.field.onChange(dateString);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form onFinish={handleSubmit(handleSubmitForm)}>
        <Form.Item label={"label"}>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name={"dob"}
            render={(props) => (
              <DatePicker
                onChange={(date, dateString) =>
                  onDatePickerChange(date, dateString, props)
                }
                value={date}                    
              />
            )}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide `defaultValues` to [useForm](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform) hook for setting **default** values:

A complete **example**, see **comments**:

```
import { DatePicker, Form } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";
import { Controller, SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

// We usually define interface/type outside component
interface IForm {
  dob: string;
}

const UserList = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm<IForm>({
    defaultValues: {
      dob: "2021-01-01", // Default value here
    },
  });

  const handleSubmitForm: SubmitHandler<IForm> = (data: IForm) => {};

  return (
    <Form onFinish={handleSubmit(handleSubmitForm)}>
      <Form.Item label="Date of Birth">
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="dob"
          render={(props) => (
            <DatePicker
              value={moment(props.field.value)} // DatePicker accepts a moment object
              onChange={(_, dateString) => {
                props.field.onChange(dateString); // No need of a state
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

#### Edit:

If you need to set the value after initial render, use [reset](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset), example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchMyData().then(() => {
    reset({
      dob: "2005-05-05", // Set another date
    });
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks. The main point of my issuse is setting the value of DatePicker to field.value of RHF so they can connect and update each other.